# Does "paying public" refer to people/citizen who pays taxes?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/NHTJPd7cnBU?t=251) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> In 2013, Grylls found himself in hot water with the local council after erecting a huge
>   metal slide that ended with a drop off a cliff face into the sea below.
>   Grylls defended his decision by saying:
>   "The slide is not for the **paying public** and therefore the health and safety is not for
>   other people.

Does "paying public" refer to people/citizen who pays taxes here?

Comment: Not quite. It means the general public (whether they pay taxes or not), who would expect the slide to be subject to health and safety regulations if they could use it for a fee. But they can't. Only Grylls' family and friends (the "other people" here) can use it, making it a private amusement and not subject to public regulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "ordinary customers who paid admission", you'll often hear "general public" in this context as well. So presumably the slide is located in a park that you pay admission to get inside of, but your admission does not include access or use of this slide.